# Buildroot - installing of the "pytest-runner" package fails

Tags: pypi, buildroot

Buildroot version: 2017-02

I need to integrate python package 'chardet' to my build. The chardet require the 'pytest-runner'package.

Case 1
The 'chardet' is marked to be integrated into build. The 'pytest-runner' is not pre-feteched and the 'chardet' package updated to the latest version (3.0.3) before the build with the scanpypi script.  When the make is run the following error message is shown indicating problems with the 'pytest-runner':

```
>>> python-chardet 3.0.3 Building
(cd /home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/build/python-chardet-3.0.3//;
PATH="/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/host/bin:/home/nnnn/bldr_lab
/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/host/usr
/bin:/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/host/usr/sbin:/home/nnnn/x-tools
/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/bin:/home/nnnn/bin:/home/nnnn/.local
/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr
/games:/usr/local/games" PYTHONPATH="/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output
/target/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfigdata/:/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot
/output/target/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/" _python_sysroot=/home
/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf
/sysroot _python_prefix=/usr _python_exec_prefix=/usr  /home/nnnn/bldr_lab
/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/python setup.py build  )
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytest-runner/: unknown
url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type: https
-- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pytest-runner
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>
['chardetect = chardet.cli.chardetect:main']})
File "/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/host/usr/lib/python2.7
/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in
__init__
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in  
fetch_build_eggs
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1091, in best_match
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1103, in obtain
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 633, in easy_install

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for   Requirement.parse('pytest-runner')
package/pkg-generic.mk:216: recipe for target '/home/nnnn/bldr_lab
/buildroot/output/build/python-chardet-3.0.3/.stamp_built' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/nnnn/bldr_lab/buildroot/output/build/python-chardet-
3.0.3/.stamp_built] Error 1

Makefile:79: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

case 2 When I try to create the 'pytest-runner' with the scanpypi the following error message is shown:

```
nnnn@xxxx:~/bldr2/buildroot$ ./support/scripts/scanpypi pytest-runner -o package
buildroot package name for pytest-runner: python-pytest-runner
Package: python-pytest-runner
Fetching package pytest-runner
Downloading package pytest-runner from https://pypi.python.org/packages/9e/4d/08889e5e27a9f5d6096b9ad257f4dea1faabb03c5ded8f665ead448f5d8a/pytest-runner-2.11.1.tar.gz...
Error: Could not install package pytest-runner
```

When I download the 'pytest-runner-2.11.1.tar.gz' from pypi manually it looks as normal pypi tar file.   Any idea what is root cause and how to solve the problem?

-timo-

Comment: Take a look at this [patch](https://github.com/thombashi/pytablewriter/commit/63fe493b73437b734e00af68bec1c3bb4407168e) and create/submit similar one for chardet.

Comment: 3.0.4 version is already in Buildroot.